# Add new menu items to Grub boot menu

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I need to remove one existing boot menu item and add two new ones related to my second disc partitions in my Grub menu. What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Grub* menu entries are auto-generated by `sudo update-grub`. Have you tried to run it ? Doesn't it suite your needs ?

Otherwise, you can use `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to **add** your custom entries. And then run `sudo update-grub` to update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

You can however **edit** manually `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to **delete** an entry. But your change will be lost the next time `update-grub` will be run by you or automatically by *ubuntu* when there is a kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB should autodetect every OS installed on a partition. You have to update the menu by using the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```