# Ubuntu 18.04 hanging at startup after updates

Tags: boot, plymouth, msi

Okay, so I have been running 18.04 on my MSI GS63 laptop since it came out with no problems whatsoever. Today I went to shut down and checked the box "Install upgrades on startup" (not exact wording but you know what I mean). Anyway, when I went to start the computer back up again, it kept hanging at at splash. After trying multiple times and getting the same result, I went into the ubuntu advanced settings. What I found there is confusing me very much. Here are the four lines that appeared:

> -Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-23-generic
>
> -Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-23-generic (recovery)
>
> -Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
>
> -Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-22-generic (recovery)

So I tried running the third line (with the 22 instead of the 23) and it booted up perfectly. However, now the only way I am able to boot into Ubuntu is by manually going into the advanced options every time and selecting that line. If I try to boot normally, splash hangs.

I am very curious. What does the 22/23 bit represent? Why are there 4 lines instead of only 2, which is what I have seen on other Ubuntu systems? I'm a total noob with this operating system stuff, but I very much want to learn and understand. But I would also like to solve this problem.

Comment: The options are what kernel to run, and parameters to pass the kernel. 4.15 with update level 23 or 22, If you select the 'recovery' option for each kernel, you'll run the kernel with 'recovery nomodeset' flags enabled, plus 'quiet splash' are also removed.  You can view your options|config in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (and compare the differences yourself if you wish).  *The /boot/grub/grub.cfg file is re-created when you have kernel upgrades, or `update-grub`...*

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I really appreciate it. So is there a way to set it so the system defaults to the level 22 kernel on startup? Or remove the level 23 kernel altogether?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader  I'd also be tempted to look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/649816/add-new-menu-items-to-grub-boot-menu  (to make your wanted 22-generic option a 'custom' default; if the issue is fixed with more updates; you can always remove the custom entry).  *By far the easiest is to 'hack' the grub.cfg file, but you'll grow tired of it...*

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I would use the link guiverc gave you to question 52963 and scroll down to the answers that explain Grub Customizer its easy for a noob to understand, follow the ppa, install steps, as pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had same problem as you and I solved by reading this https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/ .

My Kubuntu updated itself and it was stuck at boot. It's mainly because of the Nvidia driver, by default it's not using the proprietary Nvidia driver. I switched to the proprietary Nvidia driver then it can boot normally.